# How to install miniconda on Travis-CI using 32bit and 64bit architecture (linux and osx)?

Tags: linux, macos, 32bit-64bit, anaconda, travis-ci

I have a Python package that has a compiled extension that depends on `numpy`. I would like to test the package on Travis CI using Linux and OS X, as well as 64bit and 32bit architecture. Since everything else has been a pain or really slow I've resorted to using miniconda. This works well for 64bit but I'm stuck on 32bit, see the warning below:

```
WARNING:
Your system is x86_64, but you are trying to install an x86 (32-bit)
version of Miniconda2.  Unless you have the necessary 32-bit libraries
installed, Miniconda2 will not work.
We STRONGLY recommend installing the x86_64 version of Miniconda2 on
an x86_64 system.
Are sure you want to continue the installation? [yes|no]
[no] >>>
```

So my question has two parts:

1. Which `apt` or `brew` libraries do I need in order to add full 32bit support for miniconda?
2. Which arguments do I need to override that warning since it's a non-interactive environment?

This is my `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: python
sudo: false
matrix:
    include:
        - os: osx
          language: generic
          env: DEPS="numpy" PYTHON_VERSION="2.7" PYTHON_ARCH="32"
        - os: osx
          language: generic
          env: DEPS="numpy" PYTHON_VERSION="2.7" PYTHON_ARCH="64"
        - os: osx
          language: generic
          env: DEPS="numpy" PYTHON_VERSION="3.4" PYTHON_ARCH="32"
        - os: osx
          language: generic
          env: DEPS="numpy" PYTHON_VERSION="3.4" PYTHON_ARCH="64"
        - os: osx
          language: generic
          env: DEPS="numpy" PYTHON_VERSION="3.5" PYTHON_ARCH="32"
        - os: osx
          language: generic
          env: DEPS="numpy" PYTHON_VERSION="3.5" PYTHON_ARCH="64"
        - os: linux
          env: DEPS="numpy" PYTHON_VERSION="2.7" PYTHON_ARCH="32"
        - os: linux
          env: DEPS="numpy" PYTHON_VERSION="2.7" PYTHON_ARCH="64"
        - os: linux
          env: DEPS="numpy" PYTHON_VERSION="3.4" PYTHON_ARCH="32"
        - os: linux
          env: DEPS="numpy" PYTHON_VERSION="3.4" PYTHON_ARCH="64"
        - os: linux
          env: DEPS="numpy" PYTHON_VERSION="3.5" PYTHON_ARCH="32"
        - os: linux
          env: DEPS="numpy" PYTHON_VERSION="3.5" PYTHON_ARCH="64"

before_install:
    - source "ci/travis/conda_setup.sh"

install:
    - source "ci/travis/conda_install.sh"

script:
    - python -c "import numpy as np;print(np.version.version)"
```

The content of the `conda_setup.sh` script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -ev # exit on first error, print each command

MINICONDA_URL="http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda"

if [ ${PYTHON_VERSION:0:1} == "2" ]; then
    MINICONDA="Miniconda2"
else
    MINICONDA="Miniconda3"
fi
if [ ${TRAVIS_OS_NAME} == "osx" ]; then
    MINICONDA_OS="MacOSX"
else
    MINICONDA_OS="Linux"
fi
if [ ${PYTHON_ARCH} == "64" ]; then
    URL="${MINICONDA_URL}/${MINICONDA}-latest-${MINICONDA_OS}-x86_64.sh"
else
    URL="${MINICONDA_URL}/${MINICONDA}-latest-${MINICONDA_OS}-x86.sh"
fi
travis_retry wget "${URL}" -O miniconda.sh
chmod +x miniconda.sh
./miniconda.sh -b -p "${HOME}/miniconda"
export PATH="${HOME}/miniconda/bin:${PATH}"
hash -r
conda config --set always_yes yes --set changeps1 no
conda update -q conda
```

And the `conda_install.sh` script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -ev # exit on first error, print each command

if [ ${PYTHON_ARCH} == "32" ]; then
  set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1
fi
conda create -q -n testenv ${DEPS} python=${PYTHON_VERSION}
source activate testenv
conda info -a
conda list
```

Thank you for any advice.